# Fish Shell Fix Emoji Spacing iTerm2 MacOS

Tags: macos, unicode, fish, iterm2

In iTerm2 using fish shell `2.7.1` emojis do not display properly

With Unicode 9 widths turned on in iTerm, emojis are wack

[image]
**With Right Hand Prompt**
[image]
**Without Right Hand Prompt**
[image]

Without Unicode 9 widths, emojis are smushed.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to an outdated `wc-width` function in fish for determining how much space each character gets. This supposedly will be fixed in fish 3. If you want emojis to work properly in fish 2.x.x:

1. Build source from GitHub AND instead of `cmake ..` do `cmake -DINCLUDED_WCWIDTH=OFF ..`. This will use your system's `wc-width` function, which should be better when using MacOS.
2. Add `set -g fish_emoji_width 2` to `~/.config/config.fish`. This will make emojis by default have a width of 2, which should fix spacing issues.

This issue is explained in-detail [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2652).